# C# String class: No way of pushing a character to the end of the string?

Tags: c#, string, optimization

*Really???*

I've searched through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx and don't see any method that can directly push a character onto the end of a string. The best I can figure is

```
mystr.Insert(mystr.Length, newchar.ToString());
```

which seems innefficient because of the overhead involved in converting the character to a string and performing string concatenation. My particular use case looks like

```
while (eqtn[curidx] >= '0' && eqtn[curidx] <= '9') istr.Insert(istr.Length, eqtn[curidx++].ToString());
```

only because I can't think of a better way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Strings are immutable. Everytime you manipulate a string trying to change it you end up creating a new string.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable, so your code doesn't do anything. Every method on a `String` creates a new instance, it doesn't modify the existing string.

`String` class overrides `+` operator to create a new string with the character appended to the end:

```
istr = istr + eqtn[curidx++];
```

If you are doing a lot of such operations it will be more efficient to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). It's basically a mutable `String`.

You can use the [Append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet24s7b(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add a char to end. When you're ready, call `ToString` to get the constructed string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is absolutely right: you cannot push a character onto the end of a `string` because C# strings are *immutable*. Once you have an object, you are stuck with its value until you create a new `string` object.

On the other hand, creating a new string with an extra character at the end is very simple: use `+` operator overload that performs *concatenation*:

```
string s = "abc";
s += '9'; // s becomes "abc9"
```

Note that this solution is not so good for use in a loop, because if your loop runs N times you create N throw-away objects in the process. A better solution is to use `StringBuilder`, which provides a *mutable* string in C#. `StringBuilder` class has a convenient `Append` method, which pushes characters to the end of the `StringBuilder`. Once you are done building the string, call `ToString` to harvest the result as an immutable `string` object.